# Forcing .NET framework 3.5 in Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Because of compatibility reasons, I need to compile my project under .NET 3.5. However Microsoft Visual C# 2012 does not offer that option.

I'm getting this compiler error:

> The type 'System.Action' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=**3.5.0.0**

For this code:

```
powerTrader.PowerStartedCallback = delegate
{
    EmergencyMode(false);
};
powerTrader.PowerStoppedCallback = delegate
{
    EmergencyMode(true);
};
```

This is available selection in the IDE:
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have .NET 3.5 installed on the system? Because I'm very much working on 3.5 projects under VS2013.

Comment: So if I found out how to install it, it will appear in the menu? (I must admit that I didn't notice *Install additional frameworks* until now.)

Answer (score 3):

[Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are .NET 4+ only. It does not support .NET 3.5.

You have to create a normal class library project instead.

Comment: Can I change the project easily to be normal library? I didn't know that I'm selecting something special when I was starting the project.

Comment: Nope. You need to create a normal class library project from scratch and then add the source files to the new project.